# 'Fine Results' is fine?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english, slogan

I'm currently working in a slogan and my outcome so far is something like

> Fine Results, Simple Methods

However, by googling "fine results", [**the search results**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fine%20results%22) shows me that there is little to none usage of these words in that exact order.

I'm not asking for marketing advice or whatsoever, but I'm very concerned if this combination of words would sound odd to US English Speakers (which are my target audience);

And just to provide a bit more of context, by "fine results" I meant very good results. Something better than "okay results" but not exaggerated as:

- "amazing results"
- "astonishing results"
- "remarkable results"
- "wow such results"

I would be glad if anyone can help me on this or at least leave a comment telling me if it sounds strange to you or not :)

Comment: "Fine" is just... fine. It may not have such a positive connotation as you want to convey. If the results are "fine", I expect them to be "OK" but not "great". _Great_ could be an alternative?

Comment: UK 'fine' = something of a quality. US 'fine' = 'meh'. I'm with @oerkelens, you should go for something more positive like superb results. Quality results, etc. Don't go with "Wow such results, many methods" it makes you sound like a Doge.

Comment: @oerkelens `Great` is an excellent alternative. If you don't mind, answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: @Zikato `US 'fine' = 'meh'` that was what I've been trying to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: 'by "fine results" I meant very good results' - in this context,  fine definitely doesn't convey "very good", it conveys "acceptable" or "not bad."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that people interpret *fine* depends on context and dialect. In BrE, *fine* is often used to mean *something of high quality*, but in AmE it often means *meeting expectations, but nothing more*.

In a slogan *fine results, simple methods*, I understand the results to be OK, but not really that good, they are nothing special. That may not be the message you want to convey.

Imagine a restaurant slogan *OK food, reasonable prices*. It may do for  a review, but it doesn't work as a slogan to attract people (for a reasonable price, I can get better than "OK" food if I know where to go).

Without exaggerating more than one would expect in a slogan, I would suggest ***great***:

> Great results, simple methods.

*Great* means *very good* of *better than you'd expect*. It doesn't imply the results are *amazing* or *astonishing*, just that they are very good.

---

For the difference between *great* and *fine*, imagine both as an answer to *how are you doing*. If she tells you she's *fine*, it's not so good. If she says she's doing great, it's either sarcasm, or she's happy.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of synonyms for *good* that you could use, but *fine* probably isn't strong enough. In some contexts, it could be understood as meaning less than average. You'll see on the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fine)'s website that *fine* can mean bad in many contexts.

If you don't want to use good, then *satisfactory* might work well, as it has a clear meaning and will be aliterative with *simple*.

Answer (score 2):

"**Fine**" is understood to mean exceptional quality when used in common phrases such as "fine art" or "fine furniture". It loses its "punch" outside of these expressions, however. When composing a slogan, alliteration is often used for mnemonic purposes - also, temporally speaking, you might want to put "process" before "result". I'd suggest:

**"Simple Methods, Satisfying Results."**

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and put "process" before "result". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Fine results" reminds me of "good enough for Government work".

Your problem is that sloganeers do not go in for subtleties; this is a field in which hyperbole is the norm and you are in danger of sounding ambivalent, unambitious or even litigiously careful. I would say "excellent results".  Go for gold.

Comment: I agree with what you said about sloganeers. I'm just aiming for a more realistic approach as my target audience is also very down-to-earth. Thank you!